# How to Pass an Event Handler as a prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two js files.
1.Talker.js
2.Button.js

**Talker.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Button } from './Button';

class Talker extends React.Component {
  talk() {
    let speech = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      speech += 'blah ';
    }
    alert(speech);
  }

  render() {
    return <Button talk={this.talk} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Talker />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**Button.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button>
        Click me!
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

I wanted to pass the 'talk' method to 'Button' .But when i change the code

```
return <Button talk={this.talk} />;
```

in Talker class to

```
 return <Button talk={talk} />;
```

it also working fine.What is the use of 'this' key word here?Is it neccessary?
What is the difference happen when i use the second piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the `this.props.talk` in the `Button` component, so it doesn't do anything when clicked, and you also don't get an error.

You need to do two things:

1.) Add an onClick handler in your `Button` component.

`<button onClick={this.props.talk}>click me</button>`

2.) In your `Talker` component, make sure you're using `this` when you pass the prop. If you try and do `talk={talk}` you'll get an error when you click the button, as `talk` is `undefined`. What you're looking for is: `talk={this.talk}` to refer to the function `talk()` you defined in the `Talker` component.

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-syklhw?file=index.js).

Comment: Thanks.You are correct .After i changed ,             <button onClick={this.props.talk}>click me</button> on render method of Button class i got an error.When changed 'return <Button talk={talk} />;' to 'return <Button talk={this.talk} />;'  on Talker.js ,i got the expected output which is same as the output in your example.

Comment: Cool, if it helped feel free to mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 3):

Cause Button does never call `talk`. If you would accept it as a button property, e.g.:

```
 export class Button extends React.Component { 
   render() { 
      return <button onClick={this.props.talk} >Click me!</button>;
   }
 }
```

Then passing `talk` will fail, as `talk` is undefined and that cant be called. So no, it is *not* working fine. Using `this` to refer to the context is mandatory.

Comment: Thank you.You are correct.Now when i called talk  function in button it showed me an error .Then i  had to change talk.js  return <Button talk={this.talk} />; like this

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `<Button talk={talk} />;` works? Because `talk` is undefined there so I'm a bit confused. It shouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah .It worked since i haven't called 'talk' on button.But when i called it on 'Button' it showed me an error. import React from 'react';

export class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.talk}>
        Click me!
      </button>
    );
  }
}   then i used return <Button talk={this.talk} />;in talker.js.Then i got the expected output.